# Syntax Error while creating a Validation Rule to not allow user to save if field doesn't equal 0% or 100%

Tags: formula-field, validation, error, validation-rule, compile-error

I have a section in Opportunities called Pacing and in this section there is a percentage field called Pacing Total. I need to create a Validation rule for this field so that if it doesn't equal 0 OR 100 an error pops up when a user is putting % in the Period fields:

[image]

Currently this is the formula I put in, but it's giving me a Syntax Error:

Pacing_Total__c = 0 || 100

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT - Error still occurring when using the following formula - NOT(OR(Pacing_Total__c = 0,Pacing_Total__c = 100)):

[image]

Comment: Is `Pacing Total` a formula field?

Comment: @Oleksiy Yes, it's a formula field that adds Period 1 through Period 7.

Comment: see my comment to @caleb.breckon answer

Comment: @Oleksiy Error still occuring, please see edits to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pacing Total is a percentage field, the value for 100% would be 1:

```
NOT(
 OR( Pacing_Total__c = 0,
  Pacing_Total__c = 1
 )
)
```